# Python saving an eval function

Tags: python, python-2.7, eval

Say I have a function `fun(f, x, y)` where x and y are numbers and f is a string specifying a function such as `"1 / x ** 2 + y"`.

I wish to use this function `f` a lot, say a few million times, and the values of `x` and `y` change between each use.
Therefore calling `eval(f)` takes a significant amount of time as opposed to just calculating the value of the function each time. (About 50x, in my measured case.)

Is there any way to save this function `f` so that I would only have to call `eval` once?

**PS.** Please do not discuss the (un)safety of using `eval` here, I am aware of it, but this code isn't going anywhere where a 3rd party will run it, nor is it relevant to my question.

Comment: Why do you need the function to be stored as a string?

Comment: It will be input by the user.

Comment: Another option is to pre-[compile](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#compile) your expression into a code object, but Jean-François's technique is almost twice as fast.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could `eval` the `lambda`, so you just evaluate it once, and after that it's a function that you can use:

```
s = "1 / x ** 2 + y"

s = "lambda x,y: "+s
f = eval(s)
x = 2
y = 3
print(f(x,y))
```

I get `3.25`, but I can change `x` and `y` as many times I need without evaluating the expression again.

Answer (score 0):

If Jean_Francois' solution still isn't fast enough, you can take a look at numba. `f_numba = jit(f)`, and then probably also @jit the function that calls f_numba so that f_numba is inlined into the caller. Depends on your application.